# wait for ajax request till user stops typing

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, timer, livesearch

I have a  live search field which makes ajax call while typing. My problem is that it makes the call for every letter being typed.
Here is my code

in js file

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#employees_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#employees_search").attr("action"), $("#employees_search").serialize(), null , "script");
    return false;
   });
  });
```

in html file

```
<div align="center" id="empName">
  <%= form_tag employees_path, :method => 'get', :id => "employees_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Search Employees Here', id: 'search_field' %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

in controller

```
   @employees = Employee.where("department='Delivery'").paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page]).searchByEmp(params[:search][0]).order('name ASC')
```

in model

```
  def self.searchByEmp(search)
      if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "#{search}%")
      else
         scoped
      end
  end
```

Actually I need to send ajax request only after the user stops typing the word other than for every letter typed. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var liveSearchTimer;
$liveSearchInput.keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(liveSearchTimer);
  liveSearchTimer = setTimeout(liveSearchDoAjax, 500);
});
```

The request will be sent only when there has been half a second in which no key has been pressed.